# Are "arithmetic expressions" separated by commas allowed in C or we need separate statements for each?

Tags: c, comma-operator

In C, is the following  statement

```
a+=3,b=c*2,d=a+b;
```

equivalent to the following block of statements:

```
a+=3;
b=c*2;
d=a+b;
```

I am sure you got my point. Can we safely use multiple mathematical expressions separated by commas in the same statement in C? And in what cases this can pose problems?

Comment: Read about [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: yes.. they are the same..

Comment: Well, they are not *quite* the same: The former might get you some smirks, come code review day. (Many C/C++ programmers discourage the use of the comma operator for things like this.) ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: hopefully both the reviewer and the author of the code take account of the context it appears in, though. If it's just in the middle of a function, then you should use three statements. If it appears somewhere that multiple statements cannot (for example in the last clause of a `for` loop) then there might be a case for it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Agreed on the "for". That's what I had in mind when I wrote "for things like this". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier if you think of the comma-expression list you present like this:

```
((a += 3, b = c * 2), d = a + b)
```

First the innermost comma-expression is evaluated:

```
a += 3, b = c * 2
```

That expression will be evaluated in two steps:

```
a += 3
b = c * 2
```

The result of `a += 3` will be thrown away by the compiler, *but the assignment still happens*, it's just that the returned result is thrown away. The result of the first comma expression is `b` (which will be `c * 2` (whatever that is)).

The result of the first comma expression is then on the left-hand side of the next comma expression:

```
b = c * 2, d = a + b
```

Which will then be sequenced as

```
b = c * 2
d = a + b
```

The result of the expression `b = c * 2` is thrown away (but as it is still evaluated the assignment still happens), and the result of the complete expression is `d` (which is `a + b`).

The result of the whole expression will be `d`.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.

In C, the comma operator evaluates its left hand side, ignores the return value (for example the return of x = y is the new value), evaluates the right hand side and returns its result (if any). The use of the comma operator is to evaluate and get the side effects of what's on the left hand without using (e.g. discarding) its value.

Comment: By "ignores the result" do you mean in the first statement with commas, the two expressions a+=3 and b=c*2 are ignored?Do you mean a is not incremented by 3 and b is not assigned twice the value of c?

Comment: @TSingh All expressions (and assignment is an expression) returns a result. The expression `a += 3` will add `3` to `a` then return the new value. If used on the left-hand side of a comma-expression, this returned result will be ignored.

Comment: @T Singh 'ignores the result' is not the same as 'does not evaluate'. 'ignores the result' means 'this expression evaluated fully and returned a value. I don't care what the value it returned was, so I am ignoring it.'

Comment: @TSingh: In the language of the C standard, the expression `a += 3` does two things. It **main** result is that it returns a value of 3. A **side effect** is that it stores 3 in `a`. That may seem weird, because humans primarily use assignment expressions for their side effects, not their main result. However, that is how the C standard describes the behavior. The comma operator discards the main result. It does not discard side effects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I learnt an immensely helpful but new thing from you folks today.I had this idea that only functions "return" a result.Never occurred to me that expressions return values too.Your and Eric's profiles show up as the top "answerers" for C,hence I have no reason to doubt what you say & I'll drum this fact about  expressions into my head.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for clearly illustrating the difference between the "main result" and the "side effect".These stuff were new to me,even though they seem so crucial to C.

Comment: @T Singh Don't ever, EVER take anyone's word for granted unless it is independently supported :)